# Android Service: Detect if data connection is available either Wifi or Mobile Data

Tags: android, android-service, android-internet

How can I detect continuously or by schedule if data connection is available either Wifi or Mobile Data?

I need to detect it even if the app gets in foreground, background, or get killed by the system or user.

I already seen a lot of relevant question and sample code but they say that things have change in Android N and above for security reason.

Comment: do you have any idea about service in android>?

Comment: yes I already have some idea with it

Comment: you want connection available or connection connected?

Comment: connected sorry for the mistake

Comment: In Android 6.0 permissions got added, nothing about the answers "changed"

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Mihae see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is your service class working fine just add network state permission in your manifest and at runtime

    public class MyService extends Service {
        private static final String TAG = "MyService";
        private ServiceHandler serviceHandler;
        private static final int MSG_REQUEST = 1112;
        static Context context1;
        public static void startService(Context context) {
            context1=context;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(myIntent);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }


        private class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
            ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
                super(looper);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MSG_REQUEST:
                        checkNetwork();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void checkNetwork() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context1.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        String networkType = "";
        if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            Log.d("yahooooooo","WIFI");
        }
        else if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {

            networkType = "mobile";
            Log.d("yahooooooo","MOBILE");
        }
     if (!serviceHandler.hasMessages(MSG_REQUEST)) {
            serviceHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_REQUEST, 1000);//every 1 sec
        }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG, Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            handlerThread.start();
            serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (!serviceHandler.hasMessages(MSG_REQUEST)) {
                serviceHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_REQUEST);
            }


            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

            PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    1001,
                    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            assert alarmManager != null;
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, service);
        }

    }
```

//  Now call the service from Activity

```
    MyService.startService(MainActivity.this);
```

//  In Manifest

```
    <service
    android:name=".MyService"
    tools:ignore="InnerclassSeparator" />
```

Comment: just add runtime permissions for network state it will work

Comment: @Mihae just give it a try and let me know

Comment: Wouldn't be better if we use JobScheduler?

Comment: @Mihae i think handler would be better..just give it a try with both and if it will work then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code....

```
    Boolean  bs_netcheck=false;
    bs_netcheck = netCheck();
    if(!bs_netcheck)
    {
        displayAlert();
    }

public void displayAlert()
{

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Internet Connection Required...! \nPlease Check Your Internet Connection and Try Again");
    TextView title = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    title.setText("Network Error");
    title.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    title.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    title.setTextSize(20);
    builder.setCustomTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                            finishAffinity();
                        }
                    });
    builder.show();
}

public boolean netCheck()
{
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    assert conMgr != null;
    if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
            || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {
//notify user you are not online
        bs_netcheck =true;

    }
    return bs_netcheck;
}
```

Add Below permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I need an automatic detection even when the app is in background